# Need to run command on a remote server with no access to remote desktop

Tags: powershell

As the title describes I need to run a **command** on a **remote server** and I do not have access to remote desktop! I head that this should be possible using **Powershell**, but I can't find any good tutorials on this.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use **psexec.exe** (Part of Microsoft Sysinternals).

You can also use powershell.

I wrote a blogpost about these two alternatives a few days ago:

http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/executing-commands-and-programs-on-a-remote-machine-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

When using PSEXEC or PowerShell remoting you can execute a command on a remote machine, but it is not interactive with any currently logged on user. Using PowerShell requires 2.0 to be installed on your machine and remotely AND remoting must be enabled AND you must have admin rights on the remote computer.